# Moire Pattern in Safari

Tags: image, google-chrome, magento, safari, visual-glitch

I have a weird occurrence on this site: http://staging.southerntide.com/men/polos

Screenshot: https://asset1.basecamp.com/1759036/projects/5460690/attachments/101504586/df48b47e07232908a31f774699b076ca0010/large.jpg

If you scroll down to the product "STRIPED SKIPJACK POLO" in Safari you'll see a weird moire pattern happening.  I think this also occurs with Firefox and IE, but Chrome renders just fine.

I've read that Magento sometimes has moire issues with its image sizing, but I feel that isn't the case here since it's browser-specific.

Anyone else run into this or have a possible fix?

Answer (score 0):

At least part of what's going on here is that the image isn't being shown at its native size on the web page.  This means the browser has to resample it, and apparently the various browsers use different algorithms to resample images.

Here's the [full sized image](http://staging.southerntide.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/400x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/1/3/13SP_3510_1109__1_5.jpg), retrieved by selecting "View Image" in Firefox's context menu for the image on the page.